# terminator ctrl-tab key binding

Tags: key-mapping, gnome-terminator

pressing <kbd>ctrl-tab</kbd> in terminator has the same effect as pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>, but when I see the key-bindings in the setting, nothing is mapped to <kbd>ctrl-tab</kbd>, so why is <kbd>ctrl-tab</kbd> reserved?

Now, if I am working with xterm, I know a way around this. So essentially I am trying to see if there is a similar workaround.
The solution goes like,

Add the following lines to .Xresources:

```
*vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl ~Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;5;9~") \n \
    Ctrl Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;6;9~") \n
```

reload

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

and add the following lines. Here I am trying to cycle through screen windows with ctrl-tab and ctrl-shift-tab

```
# Ctrl-Tab
bindkey "^[[27;5;9~" next

# Ctrl-Shift-Tab
bindkey "^[[27;6;9~" prev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminals send characters to applications, not keys. Keys are encoded as characters or character sequences; most function keys send a sequence beginning with the escape character (character 27 = 033 = 0x1b = `^[` = `\e`).

There is no standard escape sequence corresponding to the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so most terminals send the character 9 = `^I` = TAB = `\t`, just like for a plain <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

As you've discovered, you can configure xterm to send different escape sequences through X resources. Terminator is descended from Gnome-terminal, which has very few customization capabilities (like the rest of Gnome). As far as I know, it offers no such configuration capability.

Comment: which terminal do you use?

Comment: @Forethinker xterm