# BASH ANSI-C Quoting - what is the Escape character \E

Tags: bash, quoting, ansi

According to the GNU Bash manual ([section 3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting%27)) $'\E' should expand to "an escape character (not ANSI C)". What is this escape character? Is it the character equivalent to backslash '`\`' itself whose function is to preserves the literal value of
the next character that follows?

How can it be demonstrated on the terminal, say using the command echo?

Comment: This is one of several duplicates [The difference between \e and ^\[](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89812/the-difference-between-e-and)

Answer (score 3):

`$'\E'` represents the [ASCII escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) (eg. `\x1b`/`\033`/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>), rather than a backslash:

```
% printf '%x\n' \'$'\E'
1b
```

One common use of this character is to indicate a control sequence: an alternate interpretation of a portion of subsequent bytes. For example, it's commonly used in shell prompts as part of an [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to indicate that the terminal should colour some text, or by applications to ask the terminal to position the cursor, and much more.<sup>*</sup>

```
% printf '\033[36m%s\033[0m\n' 'this is in cyan'
this is in cyan
% printf '\033[2J'  # clear the screen
```

<sup>* For most of these use cases, you usually want to use `tput` instead, though, which is terminfo aware and somewhat more intuitive to use. These two basic examples should be pretty much universally understood, though.</sup>